# Use Gitlab CI to create Angular Library and commit build files to different Gitlab repository

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, angular-library

I created an Angular Library as described here: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries.  I have already uploaded the source code to Gitlab The library is created using `ng build --prod` which creates a `dist/` folder containing the bundled files. I do not want to publish the lib to npm. I want to use a GitLab repo instead, so that I can install the lib in other Angular Projects with

```
npm install git+ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:project/example.git
```

I want to create a Gitlab CI for this. It should execute `ng build --prod` and then commit the build files to a different repository.
Does anyone know how to configure the .gitlab-ci.yml to achieve this?
Thanks a lot!

Edit: I have already figured out how to create the Angular Build Artifacts:

```
build:
 stage: build
 image: trion/ng-cli
 before_script:
  - npm ci
 script:
  - ng build --prod
 artifacts:
  expire_in: 1 day
  paths:
   - dist/
 tags:
  - docker
```

The thing missing now is committing them to a repository.

Comment: Did you find a solution since then ?